# Load the latest folder files to existing table automatically using azure data factory

Tags: dataset, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a year and month and date folder(2023/01/01), under month folder added new date folder having 4 files, every day added one date folder with 4 files, I want updated date folder with files to my existing table automatically. How to create azure pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

As your folder dates are adding every day, you can build the latest date folder structure(`yyyy/MM/dd`) in the ADF expression itself and then use copy activity to copy the files in that folder.

But consider the below two things.

- If the latest folder date is not current date.
- If the folder dates are as per the current date (it means latest folder date is current date `2023/12/06`).

**Here is a sample if the folder dates creation is as per the current date**

First use a set variable activity to get the current folder structure(`yyyy/MM/dd`) and give the below expression to store it in a variable.

```
@convertFromUtc(utcnow(), 'India Standard Time','yyyy/MM/dd')
```

Give your time zone as per this [timezones list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11#time-zones).

[image]

This will give the folder structure like this.

[image]

Now, use this variable in the copy activity wild card path. You can give `*` if you want to copy all the files to the target container or mention file name as well as per your requirement. Give the path till the container name in the source dataset and give the remaining path here.

[image]

In target dataset, I have given target container and files will be copied like this.

[image]

**If the latest folder date is not current date**, first you need to find the **n days difference between the current date and latest folder creation date** and build the folder date variable using that `n`. Use the below expression `@adddays(convertFromUtc(utcnow(), 'India Standard Time'),-n,'yyyy/MM/dd')` with `n` value in the first set variable activity.

Comment: Source side the current folder structure(yyyy/mm/dd), every day added new date folder in the month folder,

Comment: And how to trigger the pipeline, every day run once if new folder added. Please give clear screen shots, I'm getting doubt

Comment: Target is the only one existing table, source side newly added folder files into Target existing table

Comment: As you want to copy the files to a single SQL table, just add the SQL table dataset to the copy activity sink with same settings in the source. But for this all files schema should be same. Coming to trigger part- first you need to observe a common file name which is uploading in every date folder. You need to give that file name as **Blob path ends with** in the [storage event trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory#create-a-trigger-with-ui) like this https://i.imgur.com/yffgMEb.png.

Comment: Also you need to observe the time difference(in seconds) between the first file upload in source folder and all files in that. Here, what we do, we want the trigger to trigger the pipeline only one time and load all the files from source. so, add a wait activity before all the activities in the pipeline and give that time difference in seconds like this https://i.imgur.com/bkgX28V.png. When the common file in any date folder created then the trigger will trigger the pipeline and the pipeline will wait till all files created in that source folder by wait activity.

Comment: And after that all files will be loaded to your SQL target table by the copy activity.